# How to run JSLint using bash?

Tags: javascript, bash, jslint

I am trying to setup JSLint on ubuntu and create script called `jslint`. I placed it at `/usr/local/bin`. So at any place I can run `jslint somefile` (in theory).

I try to install `jslint4java` https://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/

my script has the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

for jsfile in $@;
do  /usr/bin/java \ 
    -jar /usr/local/lib/jslint4java-2.0.5.jar \ 
    "$jsfile"; 
done
```

I tried `java -jar /usr/local/lib/jslint4java-2.0.5.jar` it works, but when I try `jslint` it doesn't.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem description. Tell us what it does/doesn't do. What error message do you get? What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making a script, you can write an alias with

```
alias jslint='java -jar /usr/local/lib/jslint4java-2.0.5.jar'
```

and every time you use `jslint` after adding the alias you should get your desired behaviour. Of course, in this case the alias will have no persistence. To make it permanent, add it to `~/.bash_aliases` and make sure that your `~/.bashrc` has the following uncommented (so it properly reads the aliases from `~/.bash_aliases`). Depending on your version of Ubuntu, this might have already been done.

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```